# vuetify icon is not working with using pulgins

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

package.json

```json
    "dependencies": {
        "@mdi/js": "^7.3.67",
        "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^12.0.0",
        "axios": "^1.6.0",
        "eslint": "^8.53.0",
        "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.18.1",
        "pinia": "^2.1.7",
        "sass": "^1.69.5",
        "typescript": "^5.2.2",
        "vite-plugin-vuetify": "^1.0.2",
        "vue": "^3.3.4",
        "vue-router": "^4.2.5",
        "vuetify": "^3.3.22"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@mdi/font": "^7.3.67",
        "@types/node": "^20.8.10",
        "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.2.3",
        "material-design-icons-iconfont": "^6.7.0",
        "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
        "vite": "^4.4.5"
    },
```

vuetify.ts (setting file)

```js
import "vuetify/styles";
import { createVuetify } from "vuetify";
import * as components from "vuetify/components";
import * as directives from "vuetify/directives";
import { aliases, mdi } from "vuetify/iconsets/mdi";

// https://vuetifyjs.com/en/introduction/why-vuetify/#feature-guides
export default createVuetify({
  components,
  directives,
  icons: {
    defaultSet: "mdi",
    aliases,
    sets: {
      mdi,
    },
  },
...
```

and I set a pulgin files like this:
plugin/index.ts

```js
import vuetify from "./vuetify";
import pinia from "@/stores";
import router from "@/router";

import type { App } from "vue";

export function registerPlugins(app: App) {
  app.use(vuetify).use(router).use(pinia);
}
```

main.ts

```js
import { createApp } from "vue";
import { registerPlugins } from "@/plugins";
import App from "./App.vue";

const app = createApp(App);
registerPlugins(app);
app.mount("#app");
```

there's I have a problem with using icon:

```js
    <v-app-bar>
      <v-btn color="primary" icon @click.stop="drawer = !drawer">
        <v-icon icon="mdi-home" />
      </v-btn>
      <p>Hello World!</p>
    </v-app-bar>
    <v-main>
      <router-view class="ma-5"></router-view>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
```

[image]

If it's normal, it should see a home icon on blue section. but it is not. Please let me know if there are any additional codes that need to be provided or if there are any parts that need to be fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't seem to have imported the css:

```
import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css' // Ensure you are using css-loader
```

Here is [docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/icon-fonts/#material-design-icons).